# Build in PHPCI takes forever

Tags: php, continuous-integration, php-ci

I'm setting up Continues Integration and I'm wondering if everything should take so damn long.
My build is running for over a day in the mean time and still it's not finished.

It is a normal Laravel app with around 20 controllers, so a little time is granted, but over a day?

My config is fairly simple in my opinion:

```
build_settings:
ignore:
    - "vendor"
setup:
composer:
    action: "install"

test:
php_mess_detector:
    allow_failures: true
php_code_sniffer:
    standard: "PSR2"
php_cpd:
    allow_failures: true
php_docblock_checker:
    allowed_warnings: 10
    skip_classes: true
php_loc:
    directory: "src"
```

No errors, only the (by now) pesky status "Pending"

When I check the logs I get this error:

> 2016/01/28 08:01:32 [error] 6702#0: *4 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PHPCI\Controller' not found in /var/www/vendor/block8/b8framework/b8/Application.php on line 93" while reading response header from upstream, client: someipaddress, server: green.somedomain.com, request: "GET /assets/js/plugins/datepicker/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.en.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "green.somedomain.com", referrer: "http://green.somedomain.com/build/view/5"

I did composer update / install and I also added the following rule to the nginx configuration:

> fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME index.php;

My question is, is this normal? Is my config good? Am I forgetting something?

Comment: It doesn't sound normal. I would probably lost my patience after 5 minutes and checked logs.

Comment: I updated the question with the logs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've not set up the build runner when you set up PHPCI. The web interface merely creates the build and displays the results, you need to run the command line tool to run the builds.

There are three ways to set this up:

1. (New in 1.7 beta) PHPCI Worker w/ beanstalkd.

   - Install beanstalkd
   - Use supervisord (or similar) to run `/path/to/phpci/console phpci:worker`
2. (Recommended for 1.6 and below) PHPCI Daemon: https://www.phptesting.org/wiki/Run-Builds-Using-a-Daemon
3. (Fallback option) Cron: https://www.phptesting.org/wiki/Run-Builds-Using-Cron

Comment: So if I understand correct, I can really run a build from the web interface?

Comment: You need to have both the web interface and the console tool that actually runs the builds.

Comment: I didn't know this, neither could I pick it up from the docs. Thank you very much, 3 minutes and the build is done!